# How do I set a message in the flash when authlogic times out a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, authlogic

I have a rails app which uses authlogic for authentication. I have a 60 minute timeout set.

When a session times out the user is taken back to a basic login screen but there is no explanation given for why they have been logged out. Is there a way of setting a message in the flash so that this can be explained to the user? I'm surprised this isn't default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your own before_filter to check for a logged in user, and set the flash there, using the `stale?` method of the AuthLogic::Session module. This is how mine looks like:

```
def login_required
  if current_user_session && current_user_session.stale?
    flash[:error] = "Timeout message here" 
  end
  redirect_to_login unless logged_in?
end
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks very much. Unfortunately this breaks a few other things I'd done but that's only because it looks like I've set things up incorrectly. This explains a lot to me and has pointed me in the right direction to get my authentication working properly.
My lesson for today has been 'don't just plug things into your app without first understanding what they do/how they do it'.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but you could try to redefine the enforce_timeout method in application controller. Something like this:

```
private

def enforce_timeout
      if stale?
        self.stale_record = record
        self.record = nil
        flash[:now] = "Session timed out"
    end
  end
end
```

You may want to play around with it if it doesn't work, here's the source I looked at: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/timeout.rb

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks very much for looking at this.

Comment: No, doesn't work. I did some playing around though and got closer.
The method you've suggested overwriting can't be overridden in the application controller as far as I can tell. I was able to override it by putting it in a .rb file in config/initializers in a Authlogic::Session::Timeout::InstanceMethods.module_eval do block.
This works except I don't have access to the flash from there. I'm trying to figure this out now.

Comment: You may have the controller object available inside the module. So you should be able to call flash on that.